Trouble with DOM element display
I'm attempting to display the monthly payment in the span after apply is clicked I've even gone as far as testing it and the test won't print out either. Putting the code in its own file it is supposed to display the value. of calc() when the apply button is clicked
function calc() {
  var downpayment = parseFloat(document.getElementById('down-payment').value);
  var price       = parseInt(document.getElementById('vehiclePrice').textContent.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
  var months      = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
  var credit      = document.getElementById('credit').value;

  var interestRate;
  if (credit === 'bad') {
      interestRate = 0.12;
  } else if (credit === 'fair') {
      interestRate = 0.09;
  } else {
      interestRate = 0.075;
  }

  var loanAmount     = price - downpayment;
  var totalPayback   = loanAmount * (1 + interestRate);
  var monthlyPayment = totalPayback / months;

  document.getElementById('payment').textContent = `$${monthlyPayment.toFixed(2)}`;
};

const test = document.createElement('p');
test.textContent('it works');
document.body.appendChild(test);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estimate.css">
    <script src="paymentCalculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Car<span>Guru</span></header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Monthly Payment Estimate Calculator</h1>
        <label for="downpayment">Down Payment</label>
        <input type="number" name="down-payment" id="down-payment">
        <h2><label for="price">Vehicle Price:</label>20,000</h2>
        <h4>
            <label for="months"months>Months</label>
            <select name="months" id="months"> -
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="36">36</option>
                <option value="48">48</option>
                <option value="60">60</option>
                <option value="72">72</option>
                <option value="84">84</option>
            </select>
            
        </h4>
        <h3>
            <label for="credit-score">Credit raiting </label>
            <select name="credit-rating" id="credit">
                <option value="#">- </option>
                <option value="bad">Bad 0-590 Fico score </option>
                <option value="Fair">Fair 591-675 Fico score </option>
                <option value="Good">Good 676-800 Fico score </option>
            </select>
        </h3>
        <button id="calculatePayment">Apply</button>
        <span id="payment"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

It is supposed to display the value. of calc() when the apply button is clicked.

There's nothing in the code which would connect the button and calc function. You need to attach an event listener to the button so that calc will be called. Notice also, that the "test" fires an error, hit F12 to see the console.

textContent is not a function
test.textContent = 'it works';

instead of
test.textContent('it works');

You are finding element with id vehiclePrice which doesn't exist and it will break if you are trying to get it textContent.
Here I've created a span element which has id vehiclePrice as:
  <span id="vehiclePrice">20,000</span>

You also have to perform click operation on apply button. You can do this as:
const applyBtn = document.querySelector("#calculatePayment");
if (applyBtn) {
  applyBtn.addEventListener("click", calc);
}



function calc() {
  var downpayment = parseFloat(document.getElementById('down-payment').value);
  var price = parseInt(document.getElementById('vehiclePrice').textContent.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
  var months = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
  var credit = document.getElementById('credit').value;

  var interestRate;
  if (credit === 'bad') {
    interestRate = 0.12;
  } else if (credit === 'fair') {
    interestRate = 0.09;
  } else {
    interestRate = 0.075;
  }

  var loanAmount = price - downpayment;
  var totalPayback = loanAmount * (1 + interestRate);
  var monthlyPayment = totalPayback / months;

  document.getElementById('payment').textContent = `$${monthlyPayment.toFixed(2)}`;
};

const test = document.createElement('p');
test.textContent = 'it works';
document.body.appendChild(test);

const applyBtn = document.querySelector("#calculatePayment");
if (applyBtn) {
  applyBtn.addEventListener("click", calc);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estimate.css">
  <script src="paymentCalculator.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>Car<span>Guru</span></header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Monthly Payment Estimate Calculator</h1>
    <label for="downpayment">Down Payment</label>
    <input type="number" name="down-payment" id="down-payment">
    <h2><label for="price">Vehicle Price:</label>
      <span id="vehiclePrice">20,000</span>
    </h2>
    <h4>
      <label for="months" months>Months</label>
      <select name="months" id="months"> -
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="72">72</option>
        <option value="84">84</option>
      </select>

    </h4>
    <h3>
      <label for="credit-score">Credit raiting </label>
      <select name="credit-rating" id="credit">
        <option value="#">- </option>
        <option value="bad">Bad 0-590 Fico score </option>
        <option value="Fair">Fair 591-675 Fico score </option>
        <option value="Good">Good 676-800 Fico score </option>
      </select>
    </h3>
    <button id="calculatePayment">Apply</button>
    <span id="payment"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Also change <script src="paymentCalculator.js"></script> to <script src="paymentCalculator.js" defer></script>  read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script
